# Swift TensorFlow Lite model not for image classification

Tags: python, ios, swift, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a tf-lite model that takes in a matrix of floats of shape (1, 96, 64, 1). I want to load it in and make a prediction. I have done it easily in python but need to port this over to swift. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my python code if it is useful. Thanks!!

```
def get_model():
    # get model (get_model)
    model_path = "./model_vggish_cv2.1757-0.21.tflite"
    model = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)

    # setup model_idx
    model_idx = [0, 0]
    model_idx[0] = model.get_input_details()[0]['index']
    model_idx[1] = model.get_output_details()[0]['index']
    # input size
    input_shape = model.get_input_details()[0]['shape']
    # adjust model
    model.resize_tensor_input(
        model_idx[0], [1, input_shape[1], input_shape[2], input_shape[3]])
    model.allocate_tensors()
    return model, model_idx

model_features = model_features.reshape(
                (1, 96, 64, 1)).astype(np.float32)
model, model_idx = get_model()
model.set_tensor(model_idx[0], model_features)
model.invoke()
confidence = model.get_tensor(model_idx[1]).squeeze()
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @RoiMulia my solution was to just switch to use coreml

Comment: Awesome! We tried as well but failed. Would you consider helping us as a paid assistance? We need to verify we do it correctly, as we are going to use in production. I’d be happy to collab

Comment: @RoiMulia Sure, I'll consider. Shoot me an email at rahulrentash@gmail.com with the details and I'll get back to you soon!

Comment: Sent :) Did you get it?

Comment: @RoiMulia Yes! Getting back now!